# NoClassDefFoundError occured while initiate fragment

Tags: android, intellij-idea, noclassdeffounderror

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError occured at the first line:

```
FirstFragment firstTab = FirstFragment.newInstance(10);

mTabsAdapter.addTab(generateTabSpec(0, mTabHost),
            firstTab.getClass(), null);
```

But I'm pretty sure the Fragment exist! (it's a fragment so don't need to check if declared in Manifest.) Even refactoring its name or move to other package didn't fix the problem. Here's the stacktrace:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(23608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev.twothree.android.wtf.FirstFragment
    at dev.twothree.android.activity.FragmentTab.setupTabHost(FragmentTab.java:110)
    at dev.twothree.android.activity.FragmentTab.onCreate(FragmentTab.java:75)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4899)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is it a bug of Intell J 12.0.4? My version is Build #IC-123.169. Later I'll try it in the Eclipse, but still hope it can be resolved in Intelli J.

Answer (score 0):

After open the whole project with Eclipse, config all the dependencies ONCE AGAIN, Eclipse point out that I accidentally CAST one of the custom library class to another class. Maybe that's why no successful compiled class file existed for later invoke.

Anyway, it seems Intelli-J didn't found that error while 3rd party library is involved, it could be a bug. But the blame is also on me for not find that so obvious error.